# SVG fill (fill 'hollow' area)

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I have a SVG which is wrapped in a link. By 'default' the SVG is a bordered circle with a triangle in the middle. When the SVG is hovered over, the shape goes solid, however the triangle in the middle should be transparent showing the background behind.

I've created this effect in the CodePen below but I'd like to know if there's a better way. Maybe just using the 1 path and changing how the path is filled on hover.

http://codepen.io/moy/pen/ygNeJL

Currently I have 3 path's in the SVG. A border, triangle and a circle with a hollowed out triangle. You can see the SVG code below.

```
<a href="#" title="TITLE TEXT." class="btn-next-panel">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="icon-play">
    <path class="triangle" d="M19,35V15l16,10L19,35z"/>
    <path class="border" d="M25,0C11.2,0,0,11.2,0,25c0,13.8,11.2,25,25,25c13.8,0,25-11.2,25-25C50,11.2,38.8,0,25,0z M25,48C12.3,48,2,37.7,2,25 C2,12.3,12.3,2,25,2c12.7,0,23,10.3,23,23C48,37.7,37.7,48,25,48z"/>
    <path class="solid" d="M25,0C11.2,0,0,11.2,0,25s11.2,25,25,25s25-11.2,25-25S38.8,0,25,0z M19,35V15l16,10L19,35z" />
    </svg>
</a>
```

I show/hide each path depending on if the icon is hovered over or not. Originally I thought I could just use the `solid` path and fill the middle instead of the outer shape but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Any ideas, or should I just stick with what I have?

Comment: I don't know if this is a better approach but one alternate would be to use masking to get the effect like here - http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/KaaLre.

Comment: The approach you are using (a circle with a triangular hole, and a triangle to fill the hole) is the most obvious approach.  I don't think there is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys! First time I've tried something like this so it's appreciated! :)